# What is hapenning after *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I am kind of new about Angular2.

```
 GetYapiBelge() {
    var filterInfos = new Array<FilterInfo>();
    filterInfos.push(this.AddFilterInfo(General.Syscd, "SYSCD"));
    filterInfos.push(this.AddFilterInfo(this.YapiBelgeTurId, "YPBLGTRID"));

    this._ServiceIslemlerSvc.GetYapiBelgeBasvuruByFilter(filterInfos).subscribe((result) => this.GetYapiBelgeBasvuruByFilterCompleted(result));
}

GetYapiBelgeBasvuruByFilterCompleted(result: any)
{
    this._ActiveYapiBelgeBasvuruBec = result;

    $('#dtYapiBelge').DataTable();
    $('.collapse')
        .on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            $(this)
                .parent()
                .find(".fa-plus")
                .removeClass("fa-plus")
                .addClass("fa-minus");
        })
        .on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            $(this)
                .parent()
                .find(".fa-minus")
                .removeClass("fa-minus")
                .addClass("fa-plus");
        });

}
```

The js codes are about my grid.I found some library and  used it.
It was working when i added all clomns' item hardway.But i get them with my service it doesn't work.

When i debug it first i can see js codes' effect on my grid but after get the items it is gone.I am using ngFor on my HTML side I think i need something which makes js code triggered after ngFor finished or something like that.

Have any idea about it?

Comment: One more person doing this, so I'll say it one more time : STOP using Angular and jQuery together. Do things the Angular way, OR the jQuery way. Angular constructs the DOM, jQuery manipulates it. They're competitors with different philosophies, not complementary things. You're just loading two libraries and producing overly clumsy and complex code that can't work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *ngFor keeps a boolean variable 'last' to identify the  data is last or not.  So just assign that value to a variable and call a function if it is true. Check the following line of code. This may help you.

```
<ul>
      <li *ngFor="let i of items; let last = last">{{last ? yourFunction() : ''}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: thanks it worked :)

Comment: @gülcan yanık Welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct **ngFor** format in your HTML, that there are no other directives tied to the same element, and that the variable you are iterating over is an array.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let word of dictionary">
        {{word}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

You don't need a function your class to do anything special for **ngFor**.

Comment: i already have it but when i get my "dictionary" js codes are not working anymore

Comment: I echo @JeremyThille, but your code is still incomplete.  I have no idea what *ServiceIslemlerSvc.GetYapiBelgeBasvuruByFilter* is doing.